# How can I "cast" a type to a type that conforms to a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, casting

If I've a generic function that has a protocol requirement on its type, such as

```
func decodeDecodable<DataModel: Decodable>(ofType dataModelType: DataModel.Type, from data: Data) throws -> DataModel {
  return try JSONDecoder().decode(dataModelType, from: data)
}
```

how can I call it from a generic type that might or might conform to the protocol ?

```
// The generic DataModel can be anything
func decode<DataModel>(ofType dataModelType: DataModel.Type, from data: Data) throws -> DataModel {
  if let decodableType = dataModelType as? Decodable { // <--- what would this be?
    return try decodeDecodable(ofType: decodableType, from: data)
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't cast a value to a type and pass it to a method with generic parameters. `decodeDecodable`'s DataModel type must conform to Decodable and that type must be known at compile time.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you trying to decode the data one way if the type is decodable, and another way if it is not? Why not just write two overloads of the same method then?

Comment: Yes I think I'll have to do this. I was wondering if there'd be another way

Answer (score 0):

this approach should work

```
 if let decodableType = dataModelType.self as? Decodable.Type {
        //  conform Protocol
    } else {
    //
    }
```

or

```
if dataModelType.self is Decodable.Type {
    //  conform Protocol
} else {
//
}
```